# How to register IUrlHelper and IHttpContextAccessor i integration tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I'm trying to create integration tests for my `ASP5 MVC6` application.

In my integration tests I registered all my classes, and added some MVC specific stuff form `Startup` class:

```
_services.AddEntityFramework()
                     .AddSqlServer()
                     .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                         options =>
                             options.UseSqlServer(_configuration[ServerModulesLoader.DataDefaultConnectionConnectionstringConfigurationKey]));

            _services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            _services.AddCors();
            _services.AddMvc();
```

Everything works fine until either `IUrlHelper` or `IHttpContextAccessor` appears somewhere  in the dependencies tree.

This is how I create my controllers for tests:

```
// register all my classes
// run the code from above
_provider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();
ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance<T>(_provider);
```

Right now I registered mocks for these interfaces, but I'd rather use original implementations.

What am I missing?